# My preference screen messed up

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, rajawali

My basic preference screen looks like this and I don't know why. The funny thing is , the first time is always the charm, but if I go back and forth to the preference settings screen several times, it will look like that ever after. By the way, this is a live wallpaper using Rajawali engine. Do you think it is related to the engine? Because I never experienced this in my other live wallpapers.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:key="sharedprefs"
android:title="@string/settings_title" >

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/first_header" >

</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/more_header" >
<Preference
    android:key="market"
    android:summary="@string/market_sum"
    android:title="@string/market_title" >
</Preference>
<Preference
    android:key="bytom"
    android:summary="@string/about_sum"
    android:title="@string/about_title" >
</Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

In manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".Settings"
    android:exported="true">

</activity>
```

In activity

```
package com.mydomain.wallpaper.mywallpaper;




import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;


public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity implements         SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(Service.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this    );


}

protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
        .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
super.onDestroy();
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
    String key) {
}
}
```

Comment: I am also getting the same problem have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but I found that we had a style attribute that was causing the issue.  This post from "droidin.net" helped from 2009:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/G_WceF9dfPg

> Turned out that for whatever reason (probably just copying some 
>   example code without much thinking) I had this line in my theme.xml

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>.
```

> Once I removed it - my redrawing problem was gone